# Get the latest accumulated result of a scan instead of repeating it?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

The code below does the following:

1. Load a complete set of books by calling a `backendService`. The `backendService` returns the result as a `ReplaySubject(10)`, returning 600 books in each emitted value, for about 8 times. The reason for returning the result in chunks is to quickly provide some data to the user since each chunk takes more than a second to retrieve.
2. The `loadBooks` method then selects the title of the book and accumulates the emitted arrays to a single complete list of books.
3. The `findBooksByFilter` method is used by a book listing component. It returns an observable of a filtered array of book titles.

The question I have is what I should do differently to avoid repeating the `scan` operation each time I call the method `findBooksByFilter`. Really I am only interested in the latest accumulated value from the `_books$` observable.

```js
export class BookService  {

  constructor(private backendService: BackendService) {
    this.loadBooks();
  }

  private _bookCategoryRid = '6662c0f2.ee6a64fe.25cm75kl2.m4fvotr.e7t9hb.l892ddpqqi2971ldvj4ea';

  private _books$ = new Observable<string[]>();

  private loadBooks(): void {
    this._books$ = this.backendService.getBookDtosByCategory(this._bookCategoryRid).pipe(
      scan<AssetSearchResultItem[], string[]>((acc, curr) => {
        const v = curr.map(val => val._name);
        return acc.concat(v);
      } , [])
    );
  }

  public getBooks(): Observable<string[]> {
    return this._books$;
  }

  public findBooksByFilter(searchPhrase: string): Observable<string[]> {
    if ( !searchPhrase.trim() || searchPhrase.length < 1) {
      return this._books$;
    }
    return this._books$.pipe(
      map(
        books => {
          console.log(books);
          return books.filter(
            book => ( term.indexOf(searchPhrase) >= 0));
          }
    ));
  }


}
```

Comment: You can use `takeLast(1)` after `scan`. However, this will expect that `this.backendService.getBookDtosByCategory(...)` completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to have a kind-of "caching" mechanism to avoid calling the back-end API and reducing the result for each subscriber anew.

One way to do that is to use the `shareReplay(1)` operator. It buffers as many notifications as defined in the parameter value and sends them to each new subscriber immediately on subscribe. With the value set to 1, it sends the last received notification, making it a kind-of "cache" (that used to be the operators' name, but an actual cache has much more configuration option).

With your code this would be:

```
this._books$ = this.backendService.getBookDtosByCategory(this._bookCategoryRid).pipe(
  scan<AssetSearchResultItem[], string[]>((acc, curr) => {
    const v = curr.map(val => val._name);
    return acc.concat(v);
  } , []),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```